# how to read information about ontology using owlready2

Tags: python, owl, ontology, owlready

I am working in flask app and want to load ontology and print how many classes and how many individuals in this ontology

here is my code, it does not work

```
import flask
from owlready2 import *

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def start():
    onto_path.append("pizza.owl")
    onto = get_ontology("pizza.owl")
    onto.load()
    print(onto.classes())
    print(list(onto.individuals()))

    html = ''
    html += '<h2>clases: ' + onto.classes() + '</br>'
    html += '<h3>individuals: ' + onto.individuals()    

    return html

    #return "<h1>Distant Reading Archive</h1><p>This site is a prototype API for distant reading of science fiction novels.</p>"

app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `classes()` and `individuals()` returns a generator, so you should cast the generator into a list, and ask for the length of that object.

```
n_classes = len(list(onto.classes()))
n_individuals = len(list(onto.individuals()))
```

After that, you should have the numbers on your variables and you can concatenate them with your HTML.